# IEnumerable EntityFramework Collection Confusion

Tags: sql, .net, linq, entity-framework

I have a bit of a strange issue with two bits of code that I thought should do the same thing. Could anyone shed any light on why this code takes ages to execute:

```
IEnumerable<Account> acc_list = null;
acc_list = dbContext.Accounts;
acc_list = acc_list.Where(a => !a.Transactions.Any(t => t.isClosureTransaction));
int count = acc_list.Count();
```

While this code is instant:

```
IEnumerable<Account> acc_list = null;
acc_list = dbContext.Accounts.Where(a => !a.Transactions.Any(t => t.isClosureTransaction));
int count = acc_list.Count();
```

After some investigation using the sql profiler the second piece of code is executed in one sql, while the first one executes multiple queries for every transaction on every account.

Comment: Something to do with the use of `IEnumerable<Account>`? What happens when you try using `IQueryable<Account>` instead?

Comment: Using IQueryable did do the trick. I still didnt think that IEnumerable worked the way it did here but I guess I'll have to do some more reading.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`IQueryable` always uses deferred execution because it deals in expression trees. When you assign your `DbSet` to an `IEnumerable` it enumerates the full set which means you'll enumerate each account and will do the same when you filter and then count.

The second code sample filters the set first (you access it via the property which is an `IDbSet` which extends `IQueryable`) and so when you perform the count you are only doing it on the filtered result set.

You'll probably get better performance again by doing the following:

```
dbContext.Accounts.Count(a => !a.Transactions.Any(t => t.isClosureTransaction));
```

This will execute a count in the DB directly.

[This](http://jpreecedev.com/2013/11/24/in-the-spotlight-demystifying-iqueryable-entity-framework-6/) blog post does a good job of explaining things.